# Class method checking it's own members aren't null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

i have a model class that represents a table in a database.
The table has 7 columns so the class has 7 attributes. A few of them are allowed to be null, others are not.

So when i pass a person to a public function i check if the not allowed to be null attributes aren't null. With the normal check like

```
if(person.getName() == null || person.getSurname() == null ...)
     throw new NullPointerException();
```

I now wonder if there are any downsides of making a function in the Person class that basicly does this? Like

```
public void checkFullDataset()
{
   if(name == null || surname() == null ...)
       throw new NullPointerException();
   return;
}
```

so that whenever i work with a person, i call this method instead of manually testing all fields. Would also be of advantage if at the future the table would be changed (new field added, null/not null behaviour changed etc) cause i would only need to change this function instead of many "if's" all around the code.

Comment: I would probably go with a boolean return value, something like `public boolean isDataValid()` instead - you can use that to check if the fields are set without throwing an exception, and then optionally validate further (which field is missing, etc) or throw an Exception.

Comment: So, your just asking if your method is good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. Better to disable the empty constructor and introduce one which takes all fields as argument and put the check there.
2. If you want to add such method, it better makes session to return `boolean` similar to standard `check` function such as `hasElement()`, `hasNext()` and `iEmpty()` etc and let the user deal with it.

   ```
   public boolean checkFullDataset() {
      if(name == null || surname() == null ...)
        return false;
       return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: I was further thinking to change the method so that depending what attribute is null i throw another NPE -> if(name == null) throw new NPE("name not allowed to be null"); if(surname == null) throw new NPE("surenam not allowed to be null") and so on, thats why i wanted to throw NPE insted of giving back a boolean.

Comment: :) Change your method name to `validateDataSet` (suggestion). You can do that, but what if user doesn't call this method? If this is not fine, constructor route will not even let you instantiate the object without legitimate attributes. Make a call based on your need.

Comment: The problem is the object (the person) is created from a table in a database which can have null values, thus i can't prohibit null values when i create the object.

Comment: OK. In that case, you may want to have such method and make sure its being called. As suggested, if you like, change the name of the method to more appropriate/intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to treat your demand is to make your `Person` class immutable and use the **Builder pattern** to check for mandatory fields at initialization and **never** afterwards:

Look at this sample: http://xavimiro.blogspot.fr/2008/04/new-builder-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to have discovered is the notion "class invariant". There are programming languages, e.g. `Eiffel` where the language checks the constraints before entry and exit from every public function of the class and throws exception if they are not satisfied; pretty much what you are doing on your own.

Do also look up function pre-conditions and post-conditions, similar concept.

Depending on the code, you may find the checks to be a performance issue, in which case you can disable them for production code